# Как правильно суммировать 24-битные числа на ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

Как правильно суммировать 24-битные числа на ассемблере?

Answer (score 2):

Если имеется в виду ассемблер для x86.

Если числа "правильные" - т.е. НЕ БОЛЬШЕ 2^24-1 то можно еще добавить проверку и выставление флага переноса (CF) в зависимости от того, превысило ли значение результата 2^24-1.

например (при работе с 32-разрядными операндами, EAX, EBX - операнды, результат в EAX)

```
        ADD EAX, EBX;
        TEST EAX, 0x01000000;
        JZ ncarry;
        AND EAX, 0x00FFFFFF;
        STC;
ncarry: ...
```

как результат - в EAX - "правильное" (обрезанное) 24-битное число, в флаге CF - переполнение при 24-битном сложении (если таковое имело место.

Для 16-разрядных регистров придется модифицировать код. В частности заменить первую команду соответствующей последовательностью команд для сложения и изменить команду TEST:
Операнды - AX:BX (BX-младший), CX:DX, результат в AX:BX:

```
        ADD BX, DX;
        ADC AX, CX;
        TEST AX, 0x0100;
        JZ ncarry;
        AND AX, 0x00FF;
        STC;
ncarry: ...
```

Для ассемблера процессоров ARM еще упрощается - там есть поддержка условного выполнения команд, т.о. необходимость в условном переходе пропадает...

Comment: ВНИМАНИЕ: Исправил последовательность команд - сначала AND, потом - STC. В противном случае AND сбрасывает флаг CF. Прошу прощения за недосмотр... :(

Answer (score 0):

сложить младшие части
посмотреть CF
сложить старшие части с учетом CF

или

т.к. процессоры 32-хбитные, то не возбраняется сложить 2x 24-хбитных числа как 32-хбитные.